If and Only If Among Certain Inequalities
Consider a vector $\overline{\pi} = (1,\pi)$ where $\pi>0$ and a vector $\overline{S} = (1+r,S(\omega))$ where $r>-1$ and $S$ is a strictly positive random variable on some finite sample space $\Omega$.
Let
\begin{equation*}
a = \min_{\omega\in \Omega}{S(\omega)}\hspace{1pc}\mbox{ and }\hspace{1pc}b = \max_{\omega\in \Omega}{S(\omega)}.
\end{equation*}
I want to show that $a<\pi(1+r)<b$ if and only if there does not exist a $\overline{\xi} = (\xi^{0},\xi)$ such that $\overline{\pi}\cdot\overline{\xi}\leq 0$, with $\overline{\xi}\cdot\overline{S}(\omega)\geq 0$ for all $\omega\in \Omega$ and such that for some $\omega\in \Omega$, $\overline{\xi}\cdot\overline{S}(\omega)>0$.
To that end, I propose to prove the contrapositive, and begin by supposing that $\overline{\xi}$ is as required.
Suppose $\overline{\xi} = (\xi^{0},\xi)$ as an arbitrage opportunity. Since it is an arbitrage opportunity, $\xi^{0} + \pi \xi\leq 0$. We first show that neither of $\xi$ and $\xi^{0}$ can vanish. If $\xi^{0} = 0$, then $\pi\xi\leq 0$ and since $\pi>0$, $\xi<0$. Therefore $(1+r)\xi^{0}+S(\omega)\xi = S(\omega)\xi < 0$, a contradiction. On the other hand, if $\xi = 0$, we obtain a similar contradiction. If they are both zero, the probability that there is a positive return is zero, another contradiction. Therefore, $\xi^{0}$ and $\xi$ are both nonzero. Furthermore, $\xi$ and $\xi^{0}$ are of opposite sign. To see this, suppose $\xi>0$. Then
\begin{equation*}
\xi^{0} + \pi \xi\leq 0 \Longleftrightarrow \frac{\xi^{0}}{\xi} \leq -\pi
\end{equation*}
so $\xi^{0}/\xi<0$. On the other hand, if $\xi\leq 0$, then
\begin{equation*}
0\leq (1+r)\xi^{0} + S(\omega)\xi \Longleftrightarrow \frac{\xi^{0}}{\xi} \leq  -\frac{S(\omega)}{1+r}
\end{equation*}
and again $\xi^{0}/\xi\leq 0$. In each case, the inequality is strict because $\xi^{0}\neq 0$.
We therefore have to consider two cases: (a) $\xi>0$ (b) $\xi<0$. In both cases, we have that
\begin{equation*}
0\leq (1+r)\xi^{0} + S(\omega)\xi \leq -(1+r)\pi \xi + S(\omega)\xi
\end{equation*}
whereby
\begin{equation*}
(1+r)\pi \xi \leq S(\omega)\xi
\end{equation*}
which notably holds for all $\omega$. If $\xi>0$, this becomes
\begin{equation*}
(1+r)\pi \leq S(\omega)
\end{equation*}
and taking $\omega$ such that $S(\omega) = a$ shows that $(1+r)\pi \leq a$. If $\xi<0$, it becomes
\begin{equation*}
(1+r)\pi \geq S(\omega)
\end{equation*}
and taking $\omega$ such that $S(\omega) = b$ shows that $(1+r)\pi \geq b$. The first direction is shown.
This seems to prove one direction of the contrapositive, but does it still hold even when $\xi = 0$? It seems weird that I don't use the fact that $a$ and $b$ are the minimum and maximum of $S$ on the sample space. Also, I'm not sure how to proceed in the other direction, i.e., if $(1+r)\pi \geq b$ or $(1+r)\pi \leq a$, then there exists an appropriate $\overline{\xi}$. Am I approaching this problem in a reasonable way? Is there a clearer way to go about it or is it necessary to treat it case-by-case?
Edit: For transparency, this is a paraphrase of Exercise 1.1.2 from the 4th edition of Föllmer and Schied's Stochastic Finance.
Edit: Attempt at Other Direction
We now must show that if $a\geq (1+r)\pi$ or if $b\leq (1+r)\pi$, then there exists an arbitrage opportunity $\overline{\xi} = (\xi^{0},\xi)$ such that
\begin{align*}
\xi^{0} + \pi \xi &\leq 0\\
(1+r)\xi^{0} + S(\omega)\xi &\geq 0\\
(1+r)\xi^{0} + S(\omega_{0})\xi &> 0.
\end{align*}
for all $\omega\in \Omega$ and some $\omega_{0}\in \Omega$.
In order for the first inequality to be satisfied, we require $\xi^{0}\leq -\pi \xi$. Now we need to show that
\begin{equation*}
(1+r)\xi^{0} + S(\omega)\xi \geq 0.
\end{equation*}
If $a\geq (1+r)\pi$, take $\xi>0$ and $\xi_{0}<0$ so that
\begin{equation*}
\xi^{0}\leq -\pi \xi \Longleftrightarrow \left|\frac{\xi^{0}}{\xi}\right| \geq \pi 
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
(1+r)\xi^{0} + S(\omega)\xi \geq 0 \Longleftrightarrow -(1+r)\left|\frac{\xi^{0}}{\xi}\right| + S(\omega) \geq 0.
\end{equation*}
By the first inequality, we have
\begin{equation*}
-(1+r)\left|\frac{\xi^{0}}{\xi}\right| + S(\omega) \geq -(1+r)\pi + S(\omega)
\end{equation*}
and by assumption,
\begin{equation*}
-(1+r)\left|\frac{\xi^{0}}{\xi}\right| + S(\omega) \geq -(1+r)\pi + S(\omega) \geq -a+S(\omega).
\end{equation*}
By the definition of $a$, it is clear that
\begin{equation*}
-a+S(\omega)\geq 0
\end{equation*}
and, as long as $b\neq a$, the inequality holds strictly for at least one $\omega$.
On the other hand, if $b\leq(1+r)\pi$, take $\xi<0$ and $\xi^{0}>0$ so that
\begin{equation*}
\xi^{0}\leq -\pi \xi \Longleftrightarrow \left|\frac{\xi^{0}}{\xi}\right| \leq \pi 
\end{equation*}
and that
\begin{equation*}
(1+r)\xi^{0} + S(\omega)\xi \geq 0 \Longleftrightarrow -(1+r)\left|\frac{\xi^{0}}{\xi}\right| + S(\omega) \leq 0.
\end{equation*}
By the first inequality, we have
\begin{equation*}
-(1+r)\left|\frac{\xi^{0}}{\xi}\right| + S(\omega) \leq -(1+r)\pi + S(\omega)
\end{equation*}
and by assumption,
\begin{equation*}
-(1+r)\left|\frac{\xi^{0}}{\xi}\right| + S(\omega) \leq -(1+r)\pi + S(\omega) \leq -b+S(\omega). 
\end{equation*}
By the definition of $b$, it is clear that
\begin{equation*}
-b+S(\omega)\leq 0
\end{equation*}
and, assuming $a\neq b$, the inequality holds strictly for at least one $\omega$.

You'll need the fact that $a,b$ are the extrema to prove the opposite direction. The $\xi=0$ case can be eliminated by the condition $\bar\xi\cdot\bar S(\omega)>0$.
And your approach looks fine. When finding an appropriate $\bar\xi$, note that its appropriateness is invariant to scalar multiplication, so you really only have one degree of freedom to deal with.

Thanks for your answer! I'm a little bit confused how I'm using the fact that $a$ and $b$ are extrema. I have shown that if $\xi>0$, then  $(1+r)\pi\leq S(\omega)$ for all $\omega$, and if $\xi>0$, then $(1+r)\pi\geq S(\omega)$ for all $\omega$, and then I just chose $a$ and $b$ to prove what I needed. They work because they're some value of $S(\omega)$ and the results hold for all $\omega$, but it doesn't seem like they have to be extreme values of $S(\omega)$, right?

Ah yes that's fair. You'll need to use their extremal property to prove the opposite direction. I'll edit my answer.

Ah, OK, thanks! I'm working on the other direction now.

I've updated my question to include my work so far, but I'm stuck where I am. If I suppose $(1+r)\pi\geq b$, for example, I obtain $-b+S(\omega)\geq 0$, which does not hold for all $\omega$.

Take the other sign for $\xi$, so that the inequality goes the other way.

I just posted my final solution! If you get a second, let me know what you think. The logic in both directions was incorrect, but now I think it's OK. I feel like there has to be a neater way to prove this.

Looks good! Yes maybe some parts of the proof could be streamlined but I think any other proof would use the same main ideas that you've used.
